# iOS PayPal iOS SDK 2.11.0 have Paypal interface show shipping address

Tags: ios, paypal

All is working well, except that the PayPal iOS payment interface / screens do not show the shipping address and / or allow the user to change.

There is a way to provide a shipping address, but don't want to do this.

Would like the PayPal iOS user interface to allow the user to select the shipping address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionProvided;
payment.shippingAddress = address;
```